# Android Custom Title Bar Progress

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show in my custom title bar on which Page i am currently.

For example i have 10 pages, then i will have 10 dots horizontally and the dot which is marked is the current page.

But i dont know how i can do this dynamically.

I want to do something like this: adding my custom RelativeLayout to the titlebar

```
getWindow().setsetFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, new CustomTitleBar(this));
```

I read a lot of stuff about it, but i just found that i should i have to do it with a xml File.
But can i add dynamically drawables to this xml file then!? Or How can i do this?

EDIT:

I really dont get it..
I created a xml Layout File now with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now i want to add some Buttons to it...

```
private void setTitleBar() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar);
        rl.addView(new Button(this));
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);

    }
```

But in rl.addView(new Button(this)); i get a NullPointerException.
Why is this!?

Comment: The XML's are static and meant to be inflated when the activity or layout is created. I think it's meant that you would have to recreate this part of your activity every time. However I hear [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) will allow you to do this but only on api 11 or higher...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add drawables to the xml file by referencing them in your xml file..

By Using

```
@drawable/your_drawable
```

If this is what you are asking..

Comment: How do you mean!?

I have to add them in my Code, it depends on how many Pages i will have. I dont know this, when i create the xml File...

Comment: Well if you were to create your custom title bar in xml, that is how you would add your drawables to it.